# Calculating a column value based on datediff and curdate function in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, datediff

[image: Rent Table]

Is it possible to calculate the below fields as follows:

if there is an integer in DateDiff then the LateFee column will be populated by (DateDiff * 3)
If there is no value in DateDiff, i.e the rental is still outstanding, then the LateFee that is due currently is calculated by (Date_Due - current date) * 3

I was trying this via a stored procedure:

```
delimiter $$
create procedure calcLateFees()
begin 
select Rental_ID as "Rental ID", Platform_ID as "Platform ID",Title_ID as "Title ID",Date_Due as "Due Date",
Date_Returned as "Returned On", Datediff(CURDATE(), Date_Due) * 3 as "Late Fee Outstanding"
from tp_rental
where month (curdate() = month(now()) and CURDATE() > Date_Due;
end $$

call calcLateFees();
```

I may be going about this all wrong so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is an integer in `DayDiff` then the `LateFee` column will be populated by `(DayDiff * 3)`. If there is no value in `DayDiff` [...] then the `LateFee` that is due currently is calculated by `(Date_Due - current date) * 3`

I would translate that as the following `update` query:

```
update tp_rental
set LateFee = case
    when DayDiff is not null then DayDiff * 3
    else datediff(date_due, curdate()) * 3
end
```